# How do I tell which mode this extract uses?

Tags: harmony, modes, analysis, key-signatures

[image]

In this exercise, the key signature has two flats but it's marked as C minor. There's a footnote that simply says 'modal key signature'. How do I work out which mode to use in my harmonisation?

Comment: Where is the "note"?  Please show.  The key is Bb = G minor, C would be Dorian in this key.  You would need an Ab to create C min.  You have this in one chord in the bass,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know which mode you need to use in order to complete this exercise. You simply follow the chord symbols on the bottom.

I would hazard a guess that "ic" means the "cadential" version of the i chord and would therefore be i 6/4, but consult what the book says "ic" is before committing your answer.

Following the chord symbols on the bottom strictly will eventually lead to you using a B natural (in the V chord) and an E natural (in the I chord). At this point, fuhgheddaboudit mode-wise--no mode of any major scale contains Eb, E, and F.

Comment: Ic is how you write I in its second inversion using Extended Roman Numeral notation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral_analysis Thank you for your answer, I eventually figured out that I could complete the exercise without understanding the key signature. Will definitely study modes in greater detail in the future, though.